# Access variables in stdClass object in PHP

Tags: php, stdclass

I use the API of my CRM to receive contacts. Now, I want to access the email address of the contact:

```
$result = $api->findContacts($params);
print_r($result[0]->email);
```

returns ...

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [0] => ckauwan_t@tsp-t.com 
  [--primary] => ckauwan_t@tsp-t.com 
)
```

How can access the email address stored in [--primary] via PHP? I tried $result[0]->email->--primary etc, but does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Please, don't access those variables directly. Create a function to that returns them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$primary = '--primary';

echo $result[0]->email->{$primary};
```